# python unicode convert to Japanese character

Tags: python, unicode, python-2.x, cjk

I am trying to convert **u'\u30c9\u30e9\u30b4\u30f3'** to japanese character using python

here is my sample code

```
s = u'\u30c9\u30e9\u30b4\u30f3'.encode('utf-8')
print str(s)
```

I got this error
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Which line created the error?  I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/api/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    print (s.decode('utf-8'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419/python-unicode-and-the-windows-console

Comment: It is my test code
but still getting this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: character maps to <undefined>
import sys, codecs, locale
print sys.stdout.encoding
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter(locale.getpreferredencoding())(sys.stdout)
print sys.stdout
line = u'\u30c9\u30e9\u30b4\u30f3'
print type(line), len(line)
sys.stdout.write(line)
print line

Comment: Please don't post error messages or multi-line code fragments to the comments. That's hard to read. Edit your question and place them there, properly formatted.

Comment: The commented code (which should be edited in the question) is completely different from the question code.  The question code also doesn't produce the error claimed.  See [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

This will depend on your OS and configuration, but normally, you just print the Unicode string.  If your OS, default terminal encoding, and font support Japanese, you only need:

```
>>> s = u'\u30c9\u30e9\u30b4\u30f3'
>>> print s
ドラゴン
```

On Linux, this requires your terminal to be properly configured to (typically) UTF-8.

On Windows, you need an IDE that supports UTF-8, but if using the Windows console, you will get a `UnicodeEncodeError` unless using a localized version of Windows that supports Japanese, or [changing the system locale](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfbook-surfaccess/how-to-change-system-locale-in-windows-10-the/d7826ef0-13cd-43ea-8e01-2846d813dfed?auth=1) to Japanese.  Another workaround is to use [win-unicode-console](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/win_unicode_console/0.5) and install a Japanese console font.

My example above used the PythonWin IDE that comes with the [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) module, and also works in the Python IDLE IDE that comes with a standard Python installation.

Answer (score 2):

I had an `UnicodeEncodeError` for Japanese characters in REPL on Windows 10.

I followed Mark Tolonen's suggestion and went to

> Change system locale

in the Region settings. There was an option that said

> Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support.

I checked this option on with leaving the current system locale as English (i.e., unchanged).
After reboot, REPL started to print Japanese characters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You get s in bytes. To get the Japanese characters, use `print(s.decode('utf-8'))`.